# Adding instanced mesh react fiber threejs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm making a project where I need to generate pretty huge map. I need to generate a lot of ground blocks with trees or rocks, kinda similar to
minecraft (each block must be clickable). But I have a problem with optimization. I tried cutting render distance, adding fog, and playing
with three **instances** (I'm using **threejs fiber** library for react). Could anyone help me explain how instances work and tell me how to apply
them to my project? Hre's the code to generate it in normal way, without instancing.

```js
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Box from "./Box";
export default function Ground({
  layout,
  selectBox,
  selectedBox,
  position,
}) {
  const [boxArray, setBoxArray] = useState([]);
  const size = 20;
  let id = 0;
  useEffect(() => {
    const boxArrayCopy = [];
    for (let i = -(size / 2); i < size / 2; i++) {
      let hasTree = Math.random() > 0.99;
      for (let j = -(size / 2); j < size / 2; j++) {
        const layoutObject = layout.filter(
          (layoutObject) => layoutObject.x === i && layoutObject.y === j
        );
        const box = (
          <Box
            key={id}
            coords={{ x: j * 5, y: 0, z: i * 5 }}
            color={layoutObject.length > 0 ? layoutObject[0].color : 0x61892f}
            selectBox={selectBox}
            selectedBox={selectedBox}
            hasTree={hasTree}
            hasStone={Math.random() < 0.2}
            // just a random condition to add tree to box
          />
        );
        boxArrayCopy.push(box);
        id++;
        if (hasTree) hasTree = Math.random() > 0.5;
      }
      setBoxArray([...boxArrayCopy]);
    }
    console.log("GROUND DONE");
  }, []);
  return (
    <group position={position ?? [0, 0, 0]}>
      <Suspense fallback={null}>{boxArray}</Suspense>
    </group>
  );
}
```

Comment: You might wanna look up gltfjsx it is a command that generates a js file from a glb file and you can pass it parameters, for instance if you want an instanced mesh you cans use : npx gltfjsx somefile.glb -I
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gltfjsx

Comment: I know this tool, the problem is different. I want to create instanced mesh from my custom component (like for example js from glb file), and pass params to it. Is it possible?

Comment: Instanced mesh will work fine until a certain point, depending how many objects you want to display. So if you have let's say more than a million objects to display instanced mesh might not be enough and what you might want to do is to cut your terrain into chunks and display themselves and their content or not. You can take a look at quadtrees and here is a video explaining it a bit better :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YO_A5w_fxRQ